# custom gallery cropping window in android

Tags: android, image, android-layout, gallery

After struggling with Camera intents for too long, I have now finally created a custom camera experience for my app by using SurfaceView and the Camera api. It’s pretty awesome as I now have complete control over the picture taking experience. I would like to take control over the gallery experience as well. It’s not clear how I might do that? Any advice? Basically I am hoping for the following user experience

1. click on gallery button to view photos in your gallery
2. select a photo from the gallery
3. the selected photo shows up in a customized preview in which the user can move the photo around to select which portion to use. Notice that this is a sort of cropping that happens within a fixed area (in my case a square the size of the phone's width): no resizing allowed; the area of the picture within the window is the area used. Pretty much most of the social media apps out there do it that way. I just don’t have a clue how they manage that preview/edit-window.

What I know so far:

1. I can still use the gallery intent to let the user select the image
2. The part where I am stuck is on how to create the custom edit experience that lets the user choose an area of the image to show (fixed size square).  Again, this is not resize-cropping; but rather the user can move the image around to choose which sub-area fits the window.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: wait a second ill post full code example of how to achieve what you want

Answer (score 1):

Ok Here We Go!

Activity To Select The Image From Gallery.

```
import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

public class GalleryUtil extends Activity{
    private final static int RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE = 100;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "GalleryUtil";

    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    File photoFile = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try{
            //Pick Image From Gallery
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE); 
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(requestCode){
        case RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE:

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                try{
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                //return Image Path to the Main Activity
                Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                returnFromGalleryIntent.putExtra("picturePath",picturePath);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,returnFromGalleryIntent);     
                finish();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnFromGalleryIntent);     
                    finish();   
                }
            }else{
                Log.i(TAG,"RESULT_CANCELED");     
                Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnFromGalleryIntent);     
                finish();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Activity To Crop The Selected Image:

```
public class ImageSelecter extends Activity{

    private final int GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE=200;
    private final int RESULT_CROP = 400;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        btn_choose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Start Activity To Select Image From Gallery   
                Intent gallery_Intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GalleryUtil.class);
                startActivityForResult(gallery_Intent, GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE);
                break;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
             if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){  
                 picturePath = data.getStringExtra("picturePath");  
                 //perform Crop on the Image Selected from Gallery
                 performCrop(picturePath);
             }
        }

        if (requestCode == RESULT_CROP ) {
             if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){  
                 Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                 Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
                 // Set The Bitmap Data To ImageView
                 image_capture1.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap);                             
                 image_capture1.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
             }
        }
    }

    private void performCrop(String picUri) {
        try {
            //Start Crop Activity

            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            // indicate image type and Uri
            File f = new File(picUri);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);

            cropIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/*");
            // set crop properties
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            // indicate aspect of desired crop
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            // indicate output X and Y
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 280);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 280);

            // retrieve data on return
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, RESULT_CROP);
        }
        // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            // display an error message
            String errorMessage = "your device doesn't support the crop action!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

This all hope this will give you a head up:)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What you show is what I already have for gallery. The problem is that the user is free to decide on the area of the image (h*w). I don't want to give the user such freedom. I want something similar to iOS where the area of the crop window is set in stone and the user has to move the image around so that the desired section is visible within the window. Do you know how I might do that? +1 for helping.

Comment: oh i see yes similar you can achieve that without calling default crop but creating your own crop and giving to it this function,I'm at go now i can't post a full code,you could search how to do it while i get to home,here is how!

Comment: 1st create an custom view of canvas with square!2nd connect the square lines of canvas,and 3rd give function to cut the x,y dimensions of that cunvos,and last 4th give a function not to move all round but only move a squear:)hope this is what you want ill quick post a link of canvas crop and you play with that code,just as far as i can remember as i told you because I'm on go:)

Comment: http://adblogcat.com/a-camera-preview-with-a-bounding-box-like-google-goggles/ there he cropping BEFORE capture but no matter as soon as you understand the code you can play with it however you want:)